# How to get all the dataframe objects from a custom environment

Tags: r

I want to get all the dataframes in a script.
To do this I am running the script in a custom environment.

```
env <- new.env()
source("myScript.R", local = env)
```

The problem is with this line:

```
dfs <- ls()[sapply(mget(ls(), env), is.data.frame)]
```

which gives me the error: `Error: value for ‘env’ not found`

but when I do

```
ls(envir=env)
```

I get a character string of all the names of the objects.

What am I doing wrong?

Test environment:

```
env <- new.env()
env$d <- data.frame(a=1)
env$s <- "hello"
env$p <- data.frame(z=1)
env$x <- 2
```

I would expect "d" and "p" to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you call `ls()` without the `env` parameter, it will list only the names in the current environment. Your attempts don't seem to be passing that parameter in. Another option is to use `eapply` which is meant for running a function over objects in an environment. For example

```
names(Filter(function(x) x, eapply(env, is.data.frame)))
```

This works because `eapply` returns a named list. We can just filter for the TRUE values from `is.data.frame` and grab those names.

The problem with `mget(ls(), env)` is that `ls()` is going to return `"env"` and then `mget()` is going to look for a variable named `env` in your `env` environment which doesn't exist. You would need

```
mget(ls(envir=env), env)
```

And then you would need to do the same for the list of items you are subsetting

```
dfs <- ls(envir=env)[sapply(mget(ls(envir=env), env), is.data.frame)]
```